# How to solve captcha from Facebook signup process via Tor Browser?

Tags: captcha, facebook

1. Visit https://www.facebookcorewwwi.onion
2. Fill out Signup form
3. While the verification code arrives via email, the website loads the security check
4. the Google captcha offers text or audio options. both audio and text do not load in Tor Browser [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZcQo.png). Somehow I managed to open the audio captcha in a new tab, but the file is not playable in Tor Browser [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7opBk.png)
5. copy audio captcha link to other browser, but it's close too impossible to even understand what's being said in many of those audio captchas. When I enter the text it is not accepted

Am I not a human but a computer after all? Or are those captchas just impossible to use and much too hard for the average human being?

It's great that Facebook is offering that onion address. But signup seems impossible.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZcQo.png)[image]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7opBk.png)[image]

Comment: Try using the *"Try another text"* button.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that Tor browser's tabs are using different circuits - and that's good for anonymity. But in your case your two tabs were looking *as a different users* for the server on the other end, so that's why and how the captcha didn't matched. Using HTTPS websites make sure you will add into your Tor configuration a 443(https) port into [LongLivedPorts](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#LongLivedPorts) list - so the circuits will not be rebuilt too soon, it also prevents such kind of problems.

Comment: This isn't true, there is no need to add 443 to your `LongLivedPorts`. Tor Browser already keeps circuits open. Setting `LongLivedPorts` only means that you choose only "Stable" relays for the circuit, it will not affect how long circuits are kept for.

Comment: Actually - instead of the manuals - it helps sometimes, and because of relay selection, yes: if connection is dropping - the circuit is rebuilt

Comment: Yes, however that's unlikely to happen every time they try and it absolutely does not *"affect how long circuits are kept for"*.